# What does this Objective-C (or maybe c) syntax do?

Tags: objective-c

I came across this in some example code:

```
- (IBAction) startPlayLowNote:(id)sender {

  UInt32 noteNum = kLowNote;
  UInt32 onVelocity = 127;
  UInt32 noteCommand =   kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;

    OSStatus result = noErr;
  require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
    if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to start playing the low note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}
```

What does "logTheError:" do? What is this syntax called? Where can I go for more information on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`logtheError:` is a label.  The `require_noerr` macro has a `goto` in it that will jump to a specified label in the case of an error.  Here's a simplified and expanded goto/label example without any funny business or macros:

```
int call2Functions(void)
{
   int err = function();
   if (err)
     goto errorExit;

   err = function2();

 errorExit:
   return err;
 }
```

It's C syntax originally.  You can learn more in the C standard, section **6.8.1 Labeled statements**.

Answer (score 1):

Its a label. Programming practice has discouraged their use for the last century or two ;-) But occasionally they are useful.

In this code sample `require_noerr` is a macro which takes two arguments, it tests the first and if it is not `noErr` does a jump (`goto`) to the second argument - which must be a label.

The sample code is a bit convoluted, it is equivalent to:

```
OSStatus result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0);
if (result != noErr)
   NSLog (@"Unable to start playing the low note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a label to me. have a look at the source for require_noerr method in the line above.